# how to install the new version of react app 5.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, runtime-error, create-react-app

I've been trying to install a new app for my project.
and I have an issue running it on my vs code.
now, I was trying to uninstall from the global and its still output the same error.
did some one ran into this error lately?

The ERROR output in the terminal:
"You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
[https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/"](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/%22)

thanks ahead.

Comment: If you want a specific version, you run npm install --save react@<version> e.g. npm install --save react@16.0.0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers worked for me.

**In my case this command worked:**

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

thank you guys for your help.
ive found the solution.
i entered the following link: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

and then found this link inside that guide me through : https://gist.github.com/gaearon/4064d3c23a77c74a3614c498a8bb1c5f

and this is the solution:

If you use npm 5.1 or earlier, you can't use npx. Instead, install create-react-app globally:

npm install -g create-react-app
Now you can run:

create-react-app my-app

thanks again for the contribute!

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

npx create-react-app@latest my-app

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command to create new app with version 5.0.0

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app
```

or

run this command and clear npx cache

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

then run this command to create react app

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me. I don't know-how but what Gautam Kothari commented (in a way) above worked. I had to install the latest version of React:

In my case:

```
npm install --save react@17.0.2
```

Then I installed the latest version of create-react-app

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my_app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command

```
yarn global add create-react-app@5.0.0
```